# error while binding Json Array to listview in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I am trying to bind JSON array response to listview, but I am getting some error in my activity.cs class.What i am doing wrong. Plese help me I am newbie to android.

WCF Service response

```
[{
    "Region":"String content",
    "ID":21,
    "Msg":"String content",
    "Status":214
}]
```

**regionModel.cs**

```
public class regionModel
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string Msg { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }

    }
```

**Activity.cs**

```
 List<regionTable> regionItems = new List<regionTable>();
      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.HomeScreen);
            listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List);


                   var client = new RestClient("http://azurewebsites.net/");
            var request = new RestRequest("RegionService/GetRegions", Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            regionItems = client.Execute<List<regionTable>>(request).Data;


            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(regionItems);

        for (int i = 0; i < JA.Length(); i++)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = JA.GetJSONObject(i);
                regionItems.Add(jsonObject.GetString("ID"));    
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
               // e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


            listView.Adapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this,regionItems );
```

**HomeScreenAdapter . cs**

```
public class HomeScreenAdapter : BaseAdapter<TableItem> {
    List<TableItem> items;
    Activity context;
    public HomeScreenAdapter(Activity context, List<TableItem> items)
        : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override TableItem this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = items[position];

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomView, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.Text1).Text = item.Region;

        return view;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "getting some error" - it would be really useful if you told us exactly what error you're getting, and where.

Comment: @Jason it shows error with red mark telling that jsonobject and lenght does not contain definition.

Comment: Where?  Which specific lines?  And what is the *specific* error message?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation:  [JSONArray.Length()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Org.Json.JSONArray/) (note captial "L") and JSONArray.GetJSONObject() (capital "G") and JSONObject.GetString() (capital "G").

Xamarin tends to follow C# naming conventions, not the Java convention used by Android.

Comment: i corrected naming convection,but for this regionItems.Add(jsonObject.GetString("ID"));  it shows error  "cannot convert from string to regionModel" .

Comment: @dafodil and in JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(regionItems); for JA i am getting null values.Here i am using newton.json and restsharp libraries.

Comment: 1. regionItems is a list of regionModel, but you are trying to add a single string (ID), which won't work.  You need to deserialize the entire json object into a regionModel, then add it to the list.

Comment: 2. the Newtonsoft array is JArray.  JSONArray is a native Android class.